# Get magento product categories

Tags: magento

Hi I new to magento so this may be obvious to most experienced devs

How do i find get all the categories that a product is in.  Do i need to use collections?

I have a product model which am using like $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load() and giving the product id as parameter to load()

Now i need the category objects a product is in

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in assuming the use of collections.  Luckily for you, the product model exposes a convenient method precisely for this: [getCategoryCollection()](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L396)

You would use as follows:

```
$categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection();
```